# Rails, live audio/video streaming, recommendations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, video-streaming

What's the recommended solution to build a ruby on rails app that streams audio/video using microphone& camera, and get watched by all subscribers users ? 10 to 50 user

what's the recommended services to use ? what's the needed tools ? is there a well known media server in the rails app world that can be used for such a purpose ?

Any info is highly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We use panda for video streaming. Here is the guide to [integrate it with rails](http://www.pandastream.com/docs/integrate_with_rails)

Comment: so, do you recommend panda to start with ?

Comment: Yes, we did not face any problem with the service. It has REST-based APIs that integrate well with Rails.

Comment: Thanks Salil, I will be using it for building a school website teaching arabic language, we will have instructors giving lessons for subscribers .. I will try it .. thanks

Comment: @simo 
Hi Simo, we are starting a project that has audio/vidio streaming, I wanted to know if things went well with Panda.
thanks

Comment: Dear brother, the project wasn't completed, so I don't know if Panda is great choise, take a look at https://github.com/tong/hxmpp incase you use haxe